# How to hide the keyboard without using resignFirstResponder in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

I want to do this because I tried to receive data by using textField via BLE. But the keyboard of the iOS always shows up when the textField becomeFirstResponder. So, is there any way to dismiss the keyboard for ever?

Answer (score 0):

There is not way. I think your best option is don't use a textField. If you need to show any text you can use a label. 
Anyway I really don't understand what you mean with "I tried to receive data by using textField via BLE"

Comment: Thank you~btw, I got a bluetooth keyboard (  apple wireless keyboard ) and connect it to my iPad. Is there any way to get the  keyboard ASCII data in my app?

Comment: Please ask this as a different question, not as a comment. Beware, that very question has already been answered on StackOverflow.